# Google Maps SDK keeps using legacy renderer (version<18.0.0)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The Google Maps SDK for Android is updating to a [New Map Renderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer) in v18, which developers can try out early by explicitly opting in.

The device I am testing on has these specs:

- Samsung Galaxy S7
- Android `8.0.0` (API level 26)
- 32 GB of internal storage
- Google Play services `v21.39.18`
- app uses `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0`

Since my device meets all specs (e.g. Play services `>=21.39.14`) it should support the new renderer. **Yet debug logs indicate it is still using the legacy renderer.** A potential culprit is the `SupportMapFragment` subclass I use, but debug logs confirm that `AppCompatActivity.onMapsSdkInitialized` is called earlier than `SupportMapFragment.onCreate`. Another explanation mentioned on the page could be that the renderer is currently taken offline by Google, but I don't know any way to check this.

My app is open source, please check `Main.onCreate` (commit `86b9f637`): [source code](https://github.com/xjcl/mundraub-navigator/blob/86b9f6374a0d8b5f70db8f203bfc88e21de0e55c/app/src/main/java/xjcl/mundraub/activities/Main.kt#L327)

Comment: I was able to use the `LATEST` renderer on a Galaxy Tab S7 with Android 10, maybe the minimum required version in the article is wrong.